# Putting two fo:blocks side by side

Tags: pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm creating a PDF using Fop. I have a design that involves this:
[image]

One "div" to the left and one to the right, a border in the middle.

My current option has been to have `<fo:block />` aligned left, but then the right side would go below the left aligned fo:blocks.

[image]

How can you divide xsl into two columns? I've tried using tables and they do not show in my pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<fo:region-body column-count="2">`.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#column-count

You'll probably find that your columns have to be the same width, however.

Use `break-before="column"` on your second `fo:block`.

It's not clear what you mean by tables not showing.  I would have expected a table to work.

Comment: I was just reading one of your posts in a mailing list regarding fo:block on the same line. Small world. Anyways thank you, this worked! What I meant about tables is that, whenever I add them, my pdf just shows blank.

Comment: It's a small world!  Now that you mention it, you could try two `fo:inline-container` with fixed widths inside an `fo:block`, but FOP's conformance page shows only partial support for `fo:inline-container`, so YMMV.  Feel free to make another question about your tables problem.